# Some Controls NOT Showing in design mode VS2012 Winform Application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am developing a winform application with VB.NET using Visual Studio 2010.
I have a form filled with single split container control **Splitcontainer1**. Panel1 is filled with a datagridview and Panel2 has 2 buttons and 2 labels.
It was working fine for days, but today I only made Splitcontainer1 vertical then immediately I turned it back to horizontal. ***Panel2's controls*** disappeared, they are not showing on the form design mode, but they are still in the code of the designer. When I run the project Panel2 controls are also not showing.
Panel1 is showing the datagridview normally in design mode and when I run the application.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Close out designer and reopen? Otherwise close solution and reopen, clean and rebuild.

Comment: I tried to flip Splitcontainer1 t horizontal again, Then appeared behind the DGV!

Comment: Simplest explanation is that the controls are now covered by something else.  Use the View > Other Windows > Document Layout window.  Drag the panel up.

Comment: if you are working alone or in small team try team foundation server. Its free source control so you could go back- that's for future. For now whenever you change, and you want immediately go back Ctrl+z is your best option. if it's too late for that as well then...

Comment: @Claudius thanks for the advice and I was already used the CTRL+Z.

Comment: @Hans Passant Thanks a lot!